# TCPDF created Document: Warning: TT: nested FDEFs not allowed

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

When ill try to create a PDF with TCPDF, ill get the following error in Firebug:

```
PDF ca1e64da17eae2f8ea6f8d0c29bd5b30 [1.7 TCPDF 6.2.9 (http://www.tcpdf.org) / TCPDF] (PDF.js: 1.1.114)
Warning: TT: nested FDEFs not allowed
Warning: TT: nested FDEFs not allowed
Warning: TT: ENDF bad stack
Warning: TT: nested FDEFs not allowed
Warning: TT: ENDF bad stack
```

Ill dont find any useful information about this error. Can anyone help what is wrong here? The PDF ist about 12 Pages long, so its hard to find any error with this warning.

Ill found out that the problem only comes when ill use custom fonts - ill registered my fonts with:

```
tcpdf_addfont.php
```

in the console, and the font is showed correctly in the Browser PDF Plugin, and still when ill print the document.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Fonts are complicated things. By the sounds of it your custom font is utilising a feature that isn't supported by the Browser PDF Plugin. I had a look through the TCPDF source and I'm pretty sure the error isn't being generated in there anywhere. There is probably a tool available to validate the format/structure of your custom font file. That's the path I'd go down - figure out what aspect of your font the warning message relates to and try to change the font so that the warning goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - i will try that! The Font ive used is "OpenSans" - so normally a well popular font type.